# Excel: How can I sum the squares of values in a range meeting a criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of values.  I want to calculate what is effectively the RMSE of a range of cells based on entries in a different column.  To do that, I need the sum of squares of values within a range, meeting a specified criteria.

`SUMIF` will calculate the sum of all cells meeting a criteria.

`SUMSQ` will calculate the sum of all cells in a range, but no criteria.

How do I effectively get the combination?  Is there something like a `SUMSQIF`?

Answer (score 3):

I would use *SUMPRODUCT()*:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--(A:A="dog")*(B:B))^2)
```

for this case:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this array formula:

```
=SUMSQ(IF(A1:A10="dog",B1:B10))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Also, being an array formula one should avoid full column references.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or just:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A8="a",(B1:B8)^2))
```

The simple `IF()` test chooses the rows on which one squares the column B cell. Ordinarily, since it would produce some `FALSE` results for any given data set (or why bother at all?), you'd have to deal with those. One way would be to multiply the result of the `IF()` by 1, or do the `--` `Gary's Student` uses, but `SUM()` expects an array and is able to handle that without separately addressing it.

So, pretty near as simple as one can get for the need. Easy to understand.